# limit and integral / strong law of large

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I am currently calculating $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]^n} f\left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\right)\mathrm{d}x_1...\mathrm{d}x_n$$ with $f$ a continuous function between $[0,1]$.

We deduce that $$\int_{[0,1]^n} f\left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\right)\mathrm{d}x_1...\mathrm{d}x_n=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}\right)\right]$$ where $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent and uniforme on $[0,1]$ random variable.
With the strong law of large numbers, $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$ converge toward $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

However, I don't reach to understand how to use the dominated convergent theorem.
Indeed, I don't know how to deal with the fact that as $n$ increase, the number of integral increase too in the expression $ \int_{[0,1]^n} f\left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\right)\mathrm{d}x_1...\mathrm{d}x_n$.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Instead of thinking about Dominated Convergence Theorem on $[0,1]^n$ with Lebesgue measure, think about it on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, where your uniform random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ live on.

Comment: Oh yes ! Thanks a lot. I didn't think about the convergence in distribution with the definition  that $(X_n)$ converge in distribution toward $X$ iff for all  $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded, $E[\phi(X_n)] \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty} E[\phi(X)]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, it is also bounded. Thus $\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$ for any sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ converging weakly to $\mu$. In particular, one has $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]^n}f\left(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}\right)dx_1\dots dx_n = f(1/2)$$